# AWS: Cannot launch Windows Server 2012 R2 Base in another language than English

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch a new instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 Base, i get no way to select the language of the instance.

All guides i found advise you to select the language from the language selector (bottom left) but this will just change the web console language, the instance remains in English ...

[image]

I've checked the marketplace, Windows Server 2012 R2 Base is provided by AWS and it's supposed to be available in 19 languages, i see no way to select one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a Windows Server 2012 R2 Base AMI in a different language by  searching through all the available AMIs using the Images page instead of using the Quick Start page.

1. Open the EC2 console
2. In the navigation page, choose **AMIs**
3. Change the scope of the displayed AMIs from **Owned by me** to **Public Images**
4. In the **Search** bar you can use the following queries:

   - `amazon/Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM` : filters all the Windows Server 2012 R2 AMIs provided by Amazon.
   - `amazon/Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-French` : same as above but only the French versions.
5. Check the **Creation Date** column to get the most recent one.
6. To launch an instance from the selected AMI, right click it and then choose **Launch**.